# Finding percentage?

Tags: math

Im making a calculator and its already finished and released but now i want to update it and give it an percentage button and i want it to work.. But i have damn no idea how i will count the percentage of 2 variables..

i did try the % operator but that seemed to be something totaly else.. Didn't realy workthe way i wanted..

Anyone know how i would do this?

And let say how would the user work on a calculator? When you type on a calculator i want to count 20 out of 100% percent.. How would this work in an application.?

Comment: This sounds like homework...and if it's not, I'm not sure you're the best person to be writing a calculator :)

Comment: I can do it on paper its just the algorithn an after.. Take it easy dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think you want to divide the two values and then multiply by 100 to get the percent.  For example, let's take 5 out of 10 as an example:

100*5/10 = 500/10 = 50 which is 50% or half of the value.

Answer (score 5):

The language you are using would be helpful, but 99% of the time the % operator is the modulus operator which finds the remainder of a division of the 2 values.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

I think you might be making this harder than it has to be.  How would you figure out a percentage on paper?  Now write an algorithm that follows the steps you just completed.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the poster.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is for modulo, which is the remainder after division.  For example

`5 % 3 == 2`

You want `/` unless your language is really esoteric.

Answer (score 1):

If you want x% of y, just multiple y by (x/100).

Also, the other answers are spot on about `%` being the modulo operator, which returns the remainder of a division operation.

Answer (score 0):

The % operator is actually mod (i.e. remainder after division). You could always try:

```
int result = var * 0.2 (20% of your variable)
```

Let me know if this answers your question.